# if i have ndarray as say n=np.arange(16).reshape(4,4), which is the second to last axis?

Tags: python, numpy, numpy-ndarray

I was going through one of the documentation of NumPy module, I come across something like : **If a is an N-D array and b is an M-D array (where M>=2), it is a sum product over the last axis of a and the second-to-last axis of b**, I'm beginner to NumPy I thought there are only 2 axes 0 ( rows) and 1( columns) could someone please explain what it means? if I have ND array as say n=np.arange(16).reshape(4,4), which is the second to last axis?

Comment: For a 2d array, second to the last IS the first.  The quote applies to 3d and 4d arrays as well, anywhere `M>=2`

Answer (score 0):

when you first think of it as a simple data structure, you can think of 2-dimensional arrays as rows and columns. But here, instead of saying 0:represents row and 1:column, it is more correct to say 0:represents data and 1:represents dimensions.

In other words, you need to look at the dimension-based, not the axis-based.

```
np.arange(16).reshape(4,4)

array([[ 0,  1,  2,  3],
   [ 4,  5,  6,  7],
   [ 8,  9, 10, 11],
   [12, 13, 14, 15]])
```

Here, we get an array with n*m(4*4) ie 4 dimensions, and 16 data in it.

Below, we obtain a 2-dimensional array containing 16 data.

```
np.arange(16).reshape(8,2)

array([[ 0,  1],
   [ 2,  3],
   [ 4,  5],
   [ 6,  7],
   [ 8,  9],
   [10, 11],
   [12, 13],
   [14, 15]])
```

As for the question you want to learn.

```
a=np.arange(16).reshape(4,4)
print(a[:,-2])

array([ 2,  6, 10, 14])
```

The above expression returns data in the second-to-last dimension.